# Remember me in Laravel Auth filling username and password field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, remember-me

I am trying to implement Remember me in Laravel Auth. If a user logout, and visting to the sign in page how can I make username and password field filled in the login form?

Now, on logout it is clearing the cookie.

**\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Guard.php**

```
public function logout() {
        $user = $this->user();

        // If we have an event dispatcher instance, we can fire off the logout event
        // so any further processing can be done. This allows the developer to be
        // listening for anytime a user signs out of this application manually.
        $this->clearUserDataFromStorage();

        if ( ! is_null($this->user))
        {
            $this->refreshRememberToken($user);
        }

        if (isset($this->events))
        {
            $this->events->fire('auth.logout', [$user]);
        }

        // Once we have fired the logout event we will clear the users out of memory
        // so they are no longer available as the user is no longer considered as
        // being signed into this application and should not be available here.
        $this->user = null;

        $this->loggedOut = true;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's not how it works. The remember me flag, when set, extends the cookie lifetime, but when a users logs out, the cookie is deleted. The remember me token will work as long as the user does not log out and returns to your website at some point later in time and then (if the cookie is still valid) the user is still logged in. Auto-fill of username and password is something that happens in the browser, that will ask you if the given username/password combi should be saved, that's not something you control with your cookies.

Comment: This means If the remember cookieis valid, user will be logged in "automatically" even after the session expired isn't it?

Comment: Not after the session expired. The remember me sets a cookie with a lifespan of now() + 5 years. If the user returns without logging out (or you refreshing the remember_token) the session would still be valid.